# I am using hih9000 series temperature & humidity sensor in that first 2 byte for humidity data and last 2 byte for temperature how can i decode that

Tags: python, linux, i2c

```py
import smbus
import time
import datetime

#SMBus(0) - Raspberry Pi Model A
#SMBus(1) - Raspberry Pi Model B

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

#I2C address of sensor
address = 0x27
def temp():

     #rvalue0 = bus.read_word_data(address,0)
     rvalue0= bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,1,32)
     print rvalue0
     print ('\n')
     rvalue1 = (rvalue0 & 0x0000ff00) >> 8
     print rvalue1
     print ('\n')
     rvalue2 = rvalue0 & 0x0000ff00
     print rvalue2
     rvalue = (((rvalue2 *256) + rvalue1) >> 2 ) *.007631
     print rvalue
```

Output:

```
[79, 202, 104, 29, 63, 41, 160, 116, 252, 166, 129, 211, 242, 154, 7, 79, 202, 104, 29, 63, 41, 160, 116, 252, 166, 129, 211, 242, 154, 7, 79, 202]
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/temp1.py", line 41, in <module>
    temp()
  File "/home/pi/temp1.py", line 18, in temp
    rvalue1 = (rvalue0 & 0x0000ff00) >> 8
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: This isn't really a Pi question.  You need to look up the difference in Python between lists and numbers.  You need to study the different SMBus commands and use those appropriate to your sensor.

Comment: I believe [these are the (very minimal) docs for python's `smbus`](http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki:linux:python:smbus:doc).  Your parameters look wrong.

Comment: i had real command but still i can not understand how to decode block of data into byte of data. and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joan mentioned, you seem to misunderstand the return value provided by `read_i2c_block_data()`.  According to the documentation, and your output, it returns a `long[]`. The `&` operator *ands* a single value. Instead of a single value, you've given it a *list* (containing 32) of values.

If you want to add that operation onto every member of that list, a map function is probably your best bet. I've given an example for your first operation.

```python
def temp():
    rvalue0 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,1,32)
    print rvalue0
    print ('\n')
    rvalue1 = list(map((lambda x: (x & 0x0000ff00) >> 8), rvalue0))
    print rvalue1
```

Comment: i want to read 4 byte of data in that first 2 byte is humidity and other 2 for temp. how can i decode that

Comment: The documentation sucks, so I can't quite say for sure, but it looks like you're currently reading 32 bytes in your read function. Switch that to four, and then access the first element as `rvalue0[0]`. You can increment the number in the brackets to access each item in the array.